# RegisterClassEx invalid parameter on 64bit (but working on 32 bit)

Tags: c++, winapi

I've build a DLL that is compiled for 32 and 64 bit. The following snippet works for 32 bit, but doesn't for 64 bit (Error Code 87 - Invalid parameter)

```
const CHAR g_szClassName[] = "MyFancyDll";
...
WNDCLASSEX wndClass;
    wndClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndClass.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WinProcCallback;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hIcon = NULL;
    wndClass.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wndClass.hIconSm = NULL;
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wndClass)) {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        printf("Error registering class: %d", error);
    }
```

The code is compiled using MinGW.

So why isn't this working for 64 bit?

The command line for 32 bit is (Extracted this from my makefile macros, so sorry for any typos):

```
...
gcc -m32 -g3 -c -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ file.c -o file32.o
gcc -m64 -g3 -c -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ file.c -o file64.o

g++ -m32 -shared --enable-stdcall-fixup -static-libstdc++ file32.o -o mydll32.dll
g++ -m64 -shared --enable-stdcall-fixup -static-libstdc++ file64.o -o mydll64.dll
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Where are you getting that error?

Comment: Within the if condition at the end. The `error` variable contains `87`. `RegisterClassEx` returns a negative result, hereby the if-body is executed. I got no idea what makes the difference between 32 and 64 bit. Would it be helpful to add the compiler command line to my post?

Comment: That might, if you please

Comment: Can you try adding `memset(&wndClass, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));` right after `WNDCLASSEX wndClass;` ?

Comment: You're my hero: It works now. I didn't think of the memory used by wndClass might be dirty. Would you please write your answer as post, so I can accept it?

Comment: Specifically, you'd missed the `wndClass.hInstance` field.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but Windows uses Unicode internally throughout. You should do, too. While you're at it, you could file a defect report to the MinGW team, informing them about inappropriate default settings, specifically the option to use MBCS character encoding, a dead horse that has been dead for two decades.

Comment: Does anyone know why dirty memory is an issue when compiling the 64 bit version, but the 32bit version?

Comment: @k_wave: Asking why *undefined behavior* exposes different observable behavior for different platforms is not a valid question. The result of accessing uninitialized memory is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is leaving uninitialized memory and that might cause [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), make sure that every pointer/data is zero'ed out before proceeding setting your flags/pointers:

```
WNDCLASSEX wndClass;
memset(&wndClass, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
```

or even better:

```
WNDCLASSEX wndClass = { 0 };
```

Comment: More idiomatic would be to zeroise the variable as part of initialization. `WNDCLASSEX wndClass = { 0 }` or even set `cbSize` whilst you are at it: `WNDCLASSEX wndClass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) }`

Comment: I agree, that's another even more common way. I'll add that. Thanks